# Subtract 16 bit tiff image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff, subtraction

I have two 16 bit tiff image, of which one is a background and I have to remove it from all the image. I use the following code, however I get the error saying

> return image1._new(image1.im.chop_difference(image2.im))
> ValueError: image has wrong mode

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
    im1 = Image.open("main.tif")
    im2 = Image.open("background.tif")
    
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1)
    diff.show()
```

when I check the mode using `print(im1.mode)` I get

> I,16

I do not understand this error. Also, I don't know if Pillow is able to subtract 16 bit tiff images or not. I need help to resolve this error and get a subtracted image.

The two images are
main: [main image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djjg7j1qub213x4/main.tif?dl=0)

background image: [background](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjvu69wo2pqg8qx/background.tif?dl=0)

Comment: Maybe you'd care to share your TIFFs - using Google Drive or Dropbox or somesuch.

Comment: You appear to have shared a JPEG and a PNG via imgur, rather than 2 TIFFs via Google Drive.

Comment: I have now shared a Dropbox link, I hope you get the tiff image there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open both images and make into Numpy arrays of signed 32-bit integers
main = np.array(Image.open('main.tif')).astype('int32')
back = np.array(Image.open('background.tif')).astype('int32')

# Calculate difference with saturation
diff = np.clip(main - back, 0, main.max())

# Revert to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(diff.astype(np.uint16)).save('result.tif')
```

If you stretch the contrast, you get:

[image]